# Need documentation on method setDataTable(table), Charts service

Tags: google-apps-script

When using Charts service in GAS, you can create different type of charts and most of them have two methods `setDataTable(...)` to push data in:

```
method setDataTable(tableBuilder)
method setDataTable(table)
```

For the first one you create a `DataTableBuilder` object using `Charts.newDataTable()`.
But the second one is not documented enough for me.

Does anyone know the specification of the object **table** to transmit to the function ?
It seems to me it can be an array or a map, but I had no success in using it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second method takes in a DataTable, which is just the result of calling DataTableBuilder.build(). Unfortunately it's not possible to construct a pure JavaScript object that it will accept, and you'll need to use the DataTableBuilder.