# Cannot convert Array to Control[]. error when trying to build a dashboard

Tags: google-apps-script

Below is my code

```
function doGet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Red Book");
  var datasource = s.getDataRange();

  var DateFilter = Charts.newNumberRangeFilter().setFilterColumnLabel("Date Entered");
  var LeasingAgentFilter = Charts.newStringFilter().setFilterColumnLabel("Leasing Agent Initials").build();
  var ResolutionFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnLabel("Resolution").build();

  var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
      .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([0, 3]))
      .build();

  var tableChart = Charts.newTableChart()
    .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([1,4,5,10]))
    .build();
    Logger.log(datasource.getValues())  
  var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(datasource)  //****Error occurs here
      .bind([DateFilter, LeasingAgentFilter, ResolutionFilter], [pieChart, tableChart])
      .build();

  var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication();
  var filterPanel = uiApp.createVerticalPanel();
  var chartPanel = uiApp.createHorizontalPanel();
  filterPanel.add(DateFilter).add(LeasingAgentFilter).add(ResolutionFilter).setSpacing(10)
  chartPanel.add(tableChart).add(pieChart).setSpacing(10)

  dashboard.add(uiApp.createVerticalPanel().add(filterPanel).add(chartPanel));
  uiApp.add(dashboard);
  return uiApp;
}
```

The Logger verifies that my data is indeed there so I'm not to sure what I'm missing.  Any help is appreciated...should mention I'm new to GAS.

**9-24-14**
Have tried the following:

```
var data = datasource.getDataTable();
:
:
:
var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(data)
```

and...

```
var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(datasource.getDataTables())
```

I've eliminated all blanks in the data set just in case but to no avail.
All with the same error...I followed the instructions https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3deomYqHKgA which was done by google and it seems to work for them...not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please use the script editor menu option 'View > Execution transcript' to see what line caused the error, then update your question

Comment: Tim thanks for your reply...I did indicate where the error occurs in the code look for //****Error occurs here it is this line var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(datasource)

Comment: Sorry about the oversight - try `.setDataTable(datasource.getDataTable())`
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/dashboard-panel-builder#setDataTable%28DataTableSource%29

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: Hrm, suggestion here that you will need to use the DataTableBuilder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884524/need-documentation-on-method-setdatatabletable-charts-service

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but isn't that for building your own table using script.  I'm trying to pull existing data into the Dashboard.

Comment: Ok... Attempted var dataTable = datasource.getDataTable(true); with  var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(dataTable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working code for anyone that cares ... the issue was that I didn't have a `.build()` on the DateFilter

```
function doGet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Eh1Pm9cNAa1VeubTGWgyRJHnatVPEOgmqW7fw4TLj4s');
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Red Book");
  var data = s.getDataRange();
  //var data = datasource.getDataTable();

  var DateFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(1).build();
  var LeasingAgentFilter = Charts.newStringFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(10).build();
  var ResolutionFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(4).build();

  var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart().setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([4,10])).build();

  var tableChart = Charts.newTableChart().setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([1,4,5,10])).build();

  var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel()
      .setDataTable(data)
      .bind([DateFilter, LeasingAgentFilter, ResolutionFilter], [pieChart, tableChart])
      .build();

  var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication();
  var filterPanel = uiApp.createVerticalPanel();
  var chartPanel = uiApp.createHorizontalPanel();
  filterPanel.add(DateFilter).add(LeasingAgentFilter).add(ResolutionFilter).setSpacing(10)
  chartPanel.add(tableChart).add(pieChart).setSpacing(10)

  dashboard.add(uiApp.createVerticalPanel().add(filterPanel).add(chartPanel));
  uiApp.add(dashboard);
  return uiApp;
}
```